# JS pivot data from "wide" to "long"

Tags: javascript, json

I have tabular data that looks like this:

[image]

And ultimately what I want to achieve is this:

[image]

The data can be parsed and managed in any way, but it begins it's lifecycle in the tabular format as shown in the first picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited based on OP's comment.

Let's say input JSON looks like this:

```json
[
...
{
  "record": 1,
  "identity": "student",
  "second_identity": "visitor"
},
{
  "record": 2,
  "identity": "student",
  "second_identity": "resident"
}
...

]
```

I would convert it to this format:

```json
[
...
{
  "record": 1,
  "identity_long": "student"
},
{
  "record": 1,
  "identity_long": "visitor"
},
{
  "record": 2,
  "identity_long": "student",
},
{
  "record": 2,
  "identity_long": "resident"
}
...

]
```

Here's the code:

```js
function processData(input) {
  const output = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    const record = input[i];

    // Add "identity"
    output.push({ record: record.record, identity_long: record.identity });

    // Add "second_identity"
    output.push({ record: record.record, identity_long: record.second_identity });
  }

  return output;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer - I made the mistake of not being clear enough that the wide-to-long dataset is an essential requirement for other reasons. I have edited the question, apologies for being misleading.

Comment: No worries. I've edited my answer although the new solution. It looks too simple, not sure what you're struggling with. Please share little bit more details if you think I didn't understand the question.